# I need to make a simple file compression system for my GCSE Computer Science

Tags: python, string, integer, compression

I'm not that experienced with code and have a question pertaining to my GCSE Computer Science controlled assessment. I have got pretty far, it's just this last hurdle is holding me up.
This task requires me to use a previously made simple file compression system, and to "Develop a program that builds [upon it] to compress a text file with several sentences, including punctation. The program should be able to compress a file into a list of words and list of positions to recreate the original file. It should also be able to take a compressed file and recreate the full text, including punctuation and capitalisation, of the original file".

So far, I have made it possible to store everything as a text file with my first program:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")  
sentence = sentence.split()  
uniquewords = []  
for word in sentence:  
    if word not in uniquewords:  
        uniquewords.append(word)  

positions = [uniquewords.index(word) for word in sentence]  
recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[i] for i in positions])  

print (uniquewords)  
print (recreated)  

positions=str(positions)  
uniquewords=str(uniquewords)  

positionlist= open("H:\Python\ControlledAssessment3\PositionList.txt","w")  
positionlist.write(positions)  
positionlist.close  

wordlist=open("H:\Python\ControlledAssessment3\WordList.txt","w",)  
wordlist.write(uniquewords)  
wordlist.close
```

This makes everything into lists, and converts them into a string so that it is possible to write into a text document. Now, program number 2 is where the issue lies:

```
uniquewords=open("H:\Python\ControlledAssessment3\WordList.txt","r")
uniquewords= uniquewords.read()

positions=open("H:\Python\ControlledAssessment3\PositionList.txt","r")
positions=positions.read()

positions= [int(i) for i in positions]

print(uniquewords)
print (positions)

recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[i] for i in positions])

FinalSentence= 
open("H:\Python\ControlledAssessment3\ReconstructedSentence.txt","w")
FinalSentence.write(recreated)
FinalSentence.write('\n')
FinalSentence.close
```

When I try and run this code, this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "H:\Python\Task 3 Test 1.py", line 7, in <module>
positions= [int(i) for i in positions]
File "H:\Python\Task 3 Test 1.py", line 7, in <listcomp>
positions= [int(i) for i in positions]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['
```

So, how do you suppose I get the second program to recompile the text into the sentence? Thanks, and I'm sorry if this was a lengthy post, I've spent forever trying to get this working.
I'm assuming this is something to do with the list that has been converted into a string including brackets, commas, and spaces etc. so is there a way to revert both strings back into their original state so I can recreate the sentence? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So firstly, it is a big strange to save **positions** as a literal string; you should save each element (same with **uniquewords**). With this in mind, something like:

program1.py:

```
sentence = input("Type sentence: ")

# this is a test this is a test this is a hello goodbye yes 1 2 3 123

sentence = sentence.split()
uniquewords = []
for word in sentence:
    if word not in uniquewords:
        uniquewords.append(word)

positions = [uniquewords.index(word) for word in sentence]

with open("PositionList.txt","w") as f:
    for i in positions:
            f.write(str(i)+' ')

with open("WordList.txt","w") as f:
    for i in uniquewords:
            f.write(str(i)+' ')
```

program2.py:

```
with open("PositionList.txt","r") as f:
    data = f.read().split(' ')
positions = [int(i) for i in data if i!='']

with open("WordList.txt","r") as f:
    uniquewords = f.read().split(' ')

sentence = " ".join([uniquewords[i] for i in positions])
print(sentence)
```

PositionList.txt

```
0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

WordList.txt

```
this is a test hello goodbye yes 1 2 3 123
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to utilise this tomorrow. This makes a lot more sense. :)